# failed to rosmake rgbdslam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instruction written in [www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) [RGB-D SLAM for "Not-yet" ROS Users]
with the lastest source to compile rgbdslam. However it failed. Here are the error messages:

pastebin.com/wbRWpaAB  (sorry my karma is insufficient to publish links)

please give me some suggestion. it's urgent ! thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63574/failed-to-rosmake-rgbdslam/) by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
>   [ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/landmark.o
>   c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs>for instructions.
> ```

That is the problem. Sounds bad.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0